# Pine Script - ternary operator in "display" parameter in plot call causes invalid argument error

Tags: pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
strategy(title='Test',overlay=true)
i_hide_eq = input.bool(true, title='Hide Equity Curve')

plot(strategy.equity, display=i_hide_eq ? display.none : display.all)
plot(series=1.5, color=color.red, style=plot.style_linebr, title='Test Point')
```

Why does this code cause following error? I am using "Possible values".

**Invalid argument 'display' in 'plot' call. Possible values: [display.none, display.all]**

Answer (score 0):

Make it in this way.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title='Test',overlay=true)
i_hide_eq = input.bool(true, title='Hide Equity Curve')
plot(i_hide_eq == true ? strategy.equity : na)
plot(series=1.5, color=color.red, style=plot.style_linebr, title='Test Point')
```